# how does lambda work when it is not supplied with an argument

Tags: python

```
pat = r"(?P<one>\w+) (?P<two>\w+) (?P<three>\w+)"
repl = lambda m: m.group('two').swapcase()
ser = pd.Series(['One Two Three', 'Foo Bar Baz'])
ser.str.replace(pat, repl, regex=True)
```

```
0    tWO
1    bAR
dtype: object
```

if the argument m in lambda is not given any parameter,
how it this code able to give an output?

Comment: The lambda is never used in the given code.

Comment: You're just giving the replace method the name of the function it will have to use when replacing. It will call it when necessary, passing it the current match as parameter.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with pandas, but I'd assume that when you call that `replace` method it passes the individual regex matches to `repl` (your lambda) and that's where `m` comes from.

Answer (score 0):

> if the argument m in lambda is not given any parameter,...

Functions are objects and can be passed around before being called. This is not related specifically to `lambda`. It would work the same way with `def`:

```
at = r"(?P<one>\w+) (?P<two>\w+) (?P<three>\w+)"

def repl(m): 
    return m.group('two').swapcase()

ser = pd.Series(['One Two Three', 'Foo Bar Baz'])
ser.str.replace(pat, repl, regex=True)
```

It is not your code that explicitly wants to call `repl`. The goal here is to tell `str.replace` what it should call during the replace operation (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)]. So it is that API that will eventually call it, and will supply the argument for the parameter `m`.